# Docker OOM: Daemon should kill entire container not random process

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container running multiple processes started via docker-compose with

- mem_limit: 200m
- memswap_limit: 200m

When the memory limit is reached docker kills a random process, but I want the entire container (with all processes) to be terminated.

Is there a configuration option for that?

Edited / Additional information:

- The container runs a multi-threaded python application with each thread running in its own process.

Comment: Does _Docker_ kill the process, or the Linux kernel?  If you run only one process per container, does it mitigate the problem?

Comment: I don't know how I can see whether docker or the kernel killed the process. The container runs a multi-threaded app so I cannot move a process to another container.

Comment: If you frequently run out of memory, I'd recommend [oomd](https://github.com/facebookincubator/oomd) to preemptively kill processes before the host begins to thrash.

Answer (score 3):

If the container is killed by docker from hitting the cgroup limit, you can inspect the killed container and should see OOMKilled set to true:

```
$ docker container inspect --format '{{.State.OOMKilled}}' $container_name
false
```

If it's false like above, then most likely the kernel killed a process based on the OS running out of memory rather than the cgroup limit being reached. You should see that in the kernel logs (`/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog` usually). The lines would look like:

```
[11686.043641] Out of memory: Kill process 2603 (flasherav) score 761 or sacrifice child
[11686.043647] Killed process 2603 (flasherav) total-vm:1498536kB, anon-rss:721784kB, file-rss:4228kB
```

If the OS is killing processes, that's a sign you either need to reduce the workload on the host, tighten the cgroup limit on the container, or increase the memory available to the host (larger VM or adding RAM to the machine). If you reach the cgroup limit set on the container, docker should terminate the entire container.

Comment: I created a test container. The entrypoint script starts two python processes which allocate memory at different chunk sizes and print memory consumption. From the logs I see the process allocated larger memory chunks stop logging first. The other process continues to run. Docker inspect shows "OOMKilled": true. Docker memory limit (20mb) was well below the VMs RAM. It seems Docker doesn't kill the entire container when reaching the memory limit.